# how to make fault tolerant code when parsing JSONObject?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, algolia

currently I retrieve a JSON object from algolia like this to my app:

```
{
  "title": "Manajemen Masjid sesuai sunnah Rasulullah",
  "address": "Jl. Tebet Utara I No.40, RT.8/RW.2, Tebet Tim., Tebet, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 12820, Indonesia",
  "additionalAddress": "",
  "capacity": 0,
  "city": "Jakarta",
  "creatorIsVerified": true,
  "description": "Dua aplikasi milik Facebook",
  "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
  "eventID": "000b4e1a-f65e-4d77-83ce-d0770d344d4b",
  "eventType": "Kajian Umum",
  "_geoloc": {
    "lat": -6.2256428,
    "lng": 106.8527658
  },
  "hasBeenApproved": true,
  "numberOfContact": "081808664",
  "price": 0,
  "rankPoint": 300000000,
  "speaker": "Syafiq Reza Basalamah",
  "venue": "Aql Islamic Center 2",
  "website": "http://www.lakuin.id"
}
```

as you can see, in this record, there is no "instagram" field in the JSON above. but other records have "instagram" field in the JSON. I have problem when parsing that JSON in my Android app because not all data has "instagram" field in it.

I parse the "instagram" field using this code, If the "instagram" field is not available from incoming JSON, then I want to assign an empty string like the code below:

```
val instagram = jsonObject.get("instagram") as? String ?: ""
```

the `jsonObject` data type is java class `JSONObject` (import org.json.JSONObject)

but that line will make a crash. error message:

> Caused by: org.json.JSONException: No value for instagram
>
> E/CrashlyticsCore: Unexpected method invoked on
>   AppMeasurement.EventListener: onEvent(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle, java.lang.Long); returning null

so how to write code that can handle both case, either it has "instagram" field or not from the incoming json ?

Comment: try to use jonobject.optString("instagram","");
where the second string is the fallback string if instagram is not there or you can always put some code in the catch part of the if any exception is thrown

Comment: You really should be considering using Gson for JSON parsing; it's a lot more powerful and convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pemba Tamang suggested, use `jsonObject.optString("instagram","");` or use `gson` library, it handles errors in json

Answer (score 0):

You can use try , catch for that :

```
try{

        // try to parse ur Json here

    }catch (JSONException e){
        // here you can assign the empty String
    }
```